# mysql -how can we store Testng results to database

Tags: mysql, database, selenium, report, testng

currently working with a very large application to test (several custom programs, running in a distributed environment), and has built up a very large set of automated test cases for regression and feature testing. These tests are large and there are a lot, so full test runs are dispatched across many machines, the results gathered, and then imported into a custom web app.

technologies: `java/selenium/ant/testng/jenkins`
reports: `testng,reportng,xslt`

how to store results in database(eg: mysql)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Reporter Listener by extending the `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter` and override the `onTestSuccess`, `onTestFailure` and `onTestSkipped` methods and log the results of the tests there to mySQL. After that you have to add your custom Reporter as a Listener.

You can find on the TestNG's website, how can you define a custom Listener:

> http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

And here you can find how can you override the `TestListenerAdapter`:

> http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners